# Поиск диапазонов дат PHP

Tags: php, массивы

Есть данные в формате json, которые описывают диапазоны дат - доступен или нет. Т.е. доступно с 2014-12-28T18:50Z по 2014-12-29T11:00Z

```
[
  {"location": "EYVI", "from": "2014-12-28T18:50Z", "available": true},
  {"location": "EPWA", "from": "2014-12-29T11:00Z", "available": false},
  {"location": "EPWR", "from": "2014-12-29T13:00Z", "available": true},
  {"location": "EYVI", "from": "2014-12-29T14:00Z", "available": false}
]
```

Нужно их преобразовать в вид:

```
[
  {"location": "EYVI", "from": "2014-12-28T18:50Z", "to": "2014-12-29T11:00Z"},
  {"location": "EPWR", "from": "2014-12-29T13:00Z", "to": "2014-12-29T14:00Z"},
]
```

Чтобы данные импортировать в MySQL и производить поиск по диапазону дат.

Пробовал перебирать элементы массива при помощи foreach(), но не могу никак сделать, чтобы правильно все работало. Другими словами - не получается с foreach().

Не могу никак написать этот участок кода, который бы искал в массиве ближайшую дату с пометкой "available": false и когда ее нашел, переходил к поиску другого диапазона.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил. Сначала отсортировал весь массив по дате, потом по очереди перебор массива. К последней записи прибавляю +2 месяца.

```
function schedule($records) {
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC'); // 0 timezone

    $result = array();

    foreach ($records as $k => $v) {
        $record = array_merge($record, array(
            'available' => $v->available,
            'location' => $v->location,
            'from' => $v->from,
            'depart' => '',
            'arrive' => '',
            'to'=>   date("Y-m-d\TH:i\Z", strtotime("+2 month", strtotime($v->from)))
        ));

        if (count($records) > 1) {
            $record['to'] = date("Y-m-d\TH:i\Z", strtotime("+2 month", strtotime($record['from'])));
        }
        if (isset($records[$k+1])) {
            $record['to'] = $records[$k+1]->from;
            $record['depart'] = $v->location;
            $record['arrive'] = $records[$k+1]->location;
        }
        $result[] = $record;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Не надо искать ближайшую дату...

1. Сортируете исходный массив (по `location`, потом `from`). см. [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)
2. Проходите по отсортированному массиву и строите новый.

   - Увидели новый `location` с `available = true`, создаете ассоц. массив, соответствующий этому `location`.
   - Увидели тот же `location`, но `available = false`, записываете окончание интервала.
   - и т.д.

При этом можно добавить проверку чтоб интервалы не накладывались друг на друга, обязательно были закрытыми...